# Hibernate SaxParseException

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, netbeans, xsd

Im working in a maven project. Atm I only have entities , mappings and a configuration files. Im trying to test my hibernate mappings with junit.

I cant find the problem. I can validate the xml files in netbeans, but when i run my test I get the following error.

**Validation in netbeans:**

```
XML validation started.

Checking file:/C:/Users/Err/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PinkSocks/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml...
Referenced entity at "http://localhost:8080/files/hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd".
XML validation finished.
```

**Error:**

```
    Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
            at bleh.mihihi.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:25)
            at bleh.mihihi.utils.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
            at bleh.mihihi.utils.HibernateUtilTest.setUp(HibernateUtilTest.java:20)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2014)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1931)
            at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1910)
            at bleh.mihihi.utils.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:21)
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 25; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration http://localhost:8080/files/hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd">
        <session-factory>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/pinksocks</property>
            <property name="connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <mapping class="bleh.mihihi.Beverage" file="Beverage.hbm.xml" />
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

**Beverage.hbm.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hibernate-mapping
    xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping http://localhost:8080/files/hibernate-mapping-4.0.xsd"
        package="bleh.mihihi.entities">
        <class name="Beverage" table="beverages">
            <id name="id" column="id">
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>
            <property name="name" column="name" />
            <property name="alcohol" column="alcohol"/>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Thanks in advance

Err

Edit1:

Things I tried:

- retyping
- using dtd
- placing xsd to other places

Comment: Try to delete row in hibernate.cfg.xml and write it again by yourself. See if it works! Might be some special character or something after <hibernate-configuration.

Comment: Is this location available when testing with junit? http://localhost:8080/files/hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd

Comment: Retyping didnt work. The xsd files are deployed separately from project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Hibernate 4.x you should use the same DTD as 3.x:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
```

as you can see by this [bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6617), where the deprecation warning was removed.
Also the tutorials for 4.2 version use this, as you can see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/quickstart/en-US/html_single/files/hibernate-tutorials.zip).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to specify DTD.

Try keeping below code in both the xml files and let me know

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: I want to use the 4.0 xsd files instead of DTD's. I tried switching before, but didnt work either.

Comment: I encountered in this problem too.

Comment: Make sure you remember to remove the xsd info from the root element, too.  "xmlns" is not a valid attribute name in the hibernate mapping DTD.

Answer (score 0):

your forgot DTD in hibernate.cfg.xml file